# Change onhover image instead of onclick jssor slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider, jssor

Im using this slider
http://www.jssor.com/demos/list-slider.html

i want to change onhover thumbnail image instead of onclick thumbnail ,

Answer (score 3):

if you have downloaded the demo there is an option to change onhover of thumbnail image.

just add

```
$ActionMode : 2
```

to the

```
$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
}
```

and it will work on the thumbnail hover image.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

from [this](https://github.com/jssor/jquery-slider/blob/master/js/jssor.slider.js#L3503-L3506) source file,

```
if (_Options.$ActionMode & 1) $JssorUtils$.$AddEvent(_Wrapper, "click", OnNavigationRequest);
if (_Options.$ActionMode & 2) $JssorUtils$.$AddEvent(_Wrapper, "mouseover", OnNavigationRequest);
```

The event triggering based on `$ActionMode`.

**SOLUTION:**

You need to set option `$ActionMode : 2` to make it work with mouseover event. By default they set `$ActionMode : 1`.

In `$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {}` set `$ActionMode : 2`. This below code is from demo file of [list slider](https://github.com/jssor/jquery-slider/blob/master/demos-jquery/list-slider.source.html)

```
$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$, //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
    $ChanceToShow: 2, //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

    $Loop: 2, //[Optional] Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
    $AutoCenter: 3, //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
    $Lanes: 1, //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
    $SpacingX: 4, //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
    $SpacingY: 4, //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
    $Cols: 4, //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
    $Align: 0, //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
    $Orientation: 2, //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
    $DisableDrag: false, //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
    $ActionMode: 2
}
```

See the last line `$ActionMode:2`. `$ActionMode` is playing the role here. If you set this to `1`, it will trigger on `click` event. If you set `2`, event will trigger on `mouseover`.